# Split rows by comma into multiple rows and divide between splits

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-arrays

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet (`sheet 1`) which I use as source for a  function to split a row into several rows in a results worksheet (`sheet 2)`.
The split function divides the row when it finds commas in column `F`.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e0YhJqHn62jju7KOOy5U2JZ5FLCv6_oeY-mc_jRF5-4/edit?usp=sharing
I'd like to split the time duration in column `O` by the number of splits performed by the function in column `F` and this way calculate the accurate time spent in each operation.

Source sheet:
[image: source sheet]

Results worksheet:
[image: results sheet]

Function:

```
function extract(range, colToSplit, delimiter) {
var resArr = [], row;
range.forEach(function (r) {
    r[colToSplit-1].replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)(\d|\w)/g," , ").split(delimiter)
        .forEach(function (s) {
            row = [];
            r.forEach(function (c, k) {               
                row.push( (k === colToSplit-1) ? s.trim() : c);
            })
            resArr.push(row);
        })
})
return resArr;}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. The images doesn't the time duration and the column headers by the other hand it's not clear how are related the first and the second image.

Comment: By the way, while it could be helpful the linked spreadsheet, all the required details, included sample input/output data, to understand the question should be included on the question itself as the external content could be unavailable in the future or edited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert the data from comma-separated cells into repeated rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95635/convert-the-data-from-comma-separated-cells-into-repeated-rows)

Comment: Related [Google sheets split multi-line cell into new rows (+ duplicate surrounding row entries)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/60861/88163)